# Typo3 backend mapping from tt_content.php to ext_tables.sql

Tags: configuration, typo3, backend

I've created two input fields and a dropdown menu in the typo3 backend. When I click the save button I get the error message:

```
   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException

    An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `inputfield1` FROM `tt_content` WHERE `uid` = ?' with params [1]: Unknown column 'inputfield1' in 'field list'
```

In my ext_tables.sql I created the table with the following sql statement:

```
    CREATE TABLE tt_content (
        inputfield1 varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        inputfield2 varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        ddOne varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
    );
```

In Configuraion/TCA&Overrides/tt_content.php I created the three fields:

```
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', array(
'inputfield1' => array(
    'label' => 'Saschas Test',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'max' => 255,
        'eval' => 'trim,nospace'
    ),
),
'inputfield2' => array(
    'label' => 'Noch ein Test',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'max' => 255,
        'eval' => 'trim,nospace'
    ),
),
'ddOne' => array(
    'label' =>'My dropdownMenu',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'items' => [
            ['Author Jahr Titel'],
            ['Titel Author Jahr'],
            ['Jahr Titel Author']
    ]
        )
    )
)
```

Why does the mapping to the table tt_content not work here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you run the Database compare tool? If TYPO3v9 Under maintenance. Otherise On the install tool

Comment: let me add it as an answer and then you can acccept it

Answer (score 3):

If an extension is already installed, TYPO3 does not know if new columns have been defined and we have to do it manually.

**TYPO3 v9**

Under Maintenance and the 'card' **Analyze Database Structure Database** click **Analyse Database**

**TYPO3 v8, v7, v6**

Under the install tool Module, select the **Important actions** and then **Analyse Database**

Best regards